# Sitecore Powershell skip items in System Folder

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am a powershell newbie. I have to write a Sitecore Powershell script where I need to check all the templates for a particular value. But I need to ignore templates inside `/sitecore/templates/System/` folder.
What is the best way to implement this?

```
$items = Get-ChildItem $selectedValues.SelectedFolderPath -Recurse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Where-Object` to exclude items in `/sitecore/templates/System` node like:

```
Where-Object { ! $_.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith('/sitecore/templates/System') }
```

So your full code would be

```
$items = Get-ChildItem $selectedValues.SelectedFolderPath -Recurse | Where-Object { ! $_.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith('/sitecore/templates/System') }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below script:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/content/home" -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq 'Your Template Name'}
```

You can filter at two levels:

1. At the -Path level where you can minimize the exposure to the particular list
2. Where-Object where you can either match the TemplateIds/TemplateName with "-eq" or skip items using "-ne"

Note: -Recurse will give you all the items under the -Path specified but if you don't specify this option, you will only get the items that are just under the -Path

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below script to check for your values on the templates. It will check if the item path contains `/sitecore/templates/System`.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem $selectedValues.SelectedFolderPath -Recurse

foreach($item in $items){

    if($item.Paths.FullPath -inotmatch "/sitecore/templates/System"){
        Write-Host "Processing item $($item.Name) with path $($item.Paths.FullPath)"
        // perform your check here
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "SKIP. It is a system path for item $($item.Name) - $($item.Paths.FullPath)"
    }
}
```